# Debugging of a recursive algorithm

Tags: java, debugging, recursion

My question is if there are some smart ways of debugging complicated recursive algorithms. 
Assume that we have a complicated one (not a simple case when recursion counter is decreased in each 'nested iteration').

I mean something like recursive traversing of a graph when loops are possible.

I need to check if I am not getting endless loop somewhere. And doing this just using a debugger gives not certain answer (because I am not sure if an algorithm is in endless loop or just process as it should).

It's hard to explain it without concrete example. But what I need is...

'to check if the endless loops don't occur in let's say complicated recursive algorithm'.

Comment: Debug using print statements ?

Comment: I tried. But it slows down the execution (very) so after few minutes I don't know if the algorithm is still processing (like it should) or just it is in endless loop already. 'The objects' space for recursive iteration is 'huge' and decreasing nested logic is not simple (not each iteration decreased it by one). In simple cases the algorithm works fine.

Comment: why not post the algorithm? psuedocode? anything? this question is very vague and a proper answer depends on a lot of factors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to form a theory for why you think the algorithm does terminate. Ideally, prove the theory as a mathematical theorem.

You can look for a function of the problem state that does reduce on each recursive call. For example, see the following discussion of Ackermann's function, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Definition_and_properties)

> It may not be immediately obvious that the evaluation of A(m, n) always terminates. However, the recursion is bounded because in each recursive application either m decreases, or m remains the same and n decreases. Each time that n reaches zero, m decreases, so m eventually reaches zero as well. (Expressed more technically, in each case the pair (m, n) decreases in the lexicographic order on pairs, which is a well-ordering, just like the ordering of single non-negative integers; this means one cannot go down in the ordering infinitely many times in succession.) However, when m decreases there is no upper bound on how much n can increase — and it will often increase greatly.

That is the type of reasoning you should be thinking of applying to your algorithm.

If you cannot find any way to prove your algorithm terminates, consider looking for a variation whose termination you can prove. It is not always possible to decide whether an arbitrary program terminates or not. The trick is to write algorithms you can prove terminate.

Answer (score 3):

Best is *proving* finiteness by pre and post conditions, variants and invariants. If you can specify a (virtual) formula which value increases on every call you have a guarantee.

This is the same as proving loops to be finite. Furthermore it might make complex algorithms more tackable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to count the depth of recursive calls ... and then throw an exception if the depth of recursive calls reaches a certain threshold.

For example:

```
void TheMethod(object[] otherParameters, int recursiveCallDepth)
{
   if (recursiveCallDepth > 100) { 
      throw new Exception("...."); }
   TheMethod(otherParameters, ++recursiveCallDepth);
}
```

Comment: this *might* work in some cases, but is not a concrete answer to the ops question. highly dependent on the context of the problem.

Comment: @AlexLynch And also is a throw variant of my breakpoint suggestion, which btw i am not sure whether is better.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check for endless loops,

write a `System.out.println("no its not endless");` at the next line of calling the recursive function.

if the loop would be endless, this statement wont get print, if otherwise you will see the output

Comment: Not true, the loop might be observed after traversing many paths.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev , i dont really understand what you mean. if the program is like this

`callToRecursiveFunction()` then if in next line i write `System.out.println("");` , i dont think unless the above function will return a value,i.e. exit recursion, the SOP would execute

Comment: imagine a DFS recursive implementation. It can traverse several simple paths before encountering the first loop, which might be the only failure. If you want me i can provide you with the code.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev : Yea i do get that that a path may enter loop. Provide me code, and where you think I am suggesting to place the `SOP` please, i still dont get how what I am suggesting would fail . Thankyou :)

Comment: @MukulGoel how can you prove that the fact that you didn't get expected system.out is not because algorithm is in endless loop but because it is still processing? it is not a solution - maybe in some simple cases.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is the following:

If you have endless loop then in the graph case you will obtain a path with number of vertices greater than the total number of vertices in the graph. Assuming that the number of vertices in the graph is a global variable (which, I think, is the most common case) you can do a conditional breakpoint in the beginning of the recursion if the depth is already above the total number of vertices.

[Here is a link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint?) how you do conditional breakpoints for java in Eclipse.

Comment: *eventually* you would have traversed a path with a number of vertices greater than the total number of vertices. maybe OP's input is too big for this to be viable. if this weren't a super secret `complicated` algorithm, i would say it is pretty easy to detect whether the algorithm is stuck in a loop based on where it has traversed previously. but who knows what the op really needs. maybe the OP is allowed to cross over some nodes multiple times without being stuck in a loop (which breaks your idea)

Comment: In my case it's not so simple. Firstly my graph isn't constant. Algorithm should work on different graphs. Graphs don't have fixed structure. Connection between nodes can depend on some values in nodes. Moreover nodes can be visited multiple times.

Comment: @ŁukaszRzeszotarski Of course - my solution works for generic graphs, dynamically inputted by the user. You can easily make conditional breakpoint dependent on class variables e.g. `nodeNumber < DFSDepth`.